# Go Compiler for Windows

Tags: go

I have found in some web article that go has Windows compiler. Can anybody suggest me the web address where I can download it and some information about how to install it and commands for run a code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/WindowsPort -- **experimental**.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsSupport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go Windows downloads](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list)